# Deleting an object with Axios, Vue, Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

i'm trying to delete an object both from my view & my mySQL DB, however i'm encountering this error:
`DELETE http://localhost:8000/api/machines/[object%20MouseEvent] 404 (Not Found)`

If i remove the axios call, this method deletes the object from the view (of course when i reload the page it's back because i don't persist it to the DB.

Here's how the method looks:

```
removeElement(index) {
 axios
  .delete("machines/" + index)
  .then(res => {
   confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?") &&
   this.machines.splice(index, 1);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
},
```

Here's how the route looks:

```
 Route::delete('machines/{id}', [
  'as' => 'machines/{id}',
  'uses' => 'MachineController@destroy'
  ]);
```

And here's how the controller looks:

```
public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
 {
   $machines = Machine::findOrFail($request->id)->delete();
 }
```

Can someone help me out or atleast point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> http://localhost:8000/api/machines/[object%20MouseEvent]

this isnt correct URL. Looks like you need to get machine ID instead and use it request.

Try to use `removeElement(machine.id)` instead of that you are doing now.

If that's not enough, please share vue/js code with `removeElement` call in it

Comment: Here's with the id parameter:

`removeElement(machines) {
      axios
        .delete("machines/" + this.machines.id)
        .then(res => {
          confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?") &&
            this.machines.splice(index, 1);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },`

Now i'm getting:

`DELETE http://localhost:8000/api/machines/undefined 404 (Not Found)`
So it appears that i'm not passing the ID correctly.

Comment: I've managed to solve my issue by passing the id correctly, thank you for your feedback kind sir!